# How to iterate through each property of a custom vb.net list object when the list is empty?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a class

```
Public Class Class1
     Private _Key As Integer
     Private _Value As String
...
End Class
```

both *_key* and *_value* have public properties. Then I have a generic list

```
dim obj as New List(of Class1)
```

when **obj.count > 1** I can get the properties using **Reflection** with no problems

```
dim pi() As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj(0).GetType().GetProperties() //or any valid index for what is worth.
```

But when the list is empty, using

```
dim pi() As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

won't get me the properties **key** and **value**.

How can I get those properties (through Reflection or any other means) when the list is instancied but empty (**obj.count = 0**)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim listType = myList.GetType()
Dim itemType = listType.GenericTypeArguments.First()
```

That `itemType` variable now contains the same `Type` as your previous `obj(0).GetType()` returned.

Note that that `GenericTypeArguments` property is for .NET 4.5 or later.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any option for older versios of the framework?

Comment: I'm sure there is but I'm not sure what it would be off the top of my head and I don;t have time to look right now.  If noone else has answered by the time I'm able, I'll d a bit of research and see what I can see.